# Python: Fusing two separate objects into one?

Tags: python, python-2.7

bit of an odd question here. If I have two separate objects, each with their own variables and functions, is there any way those two objects can be combined into one single object?

To be more specific: I have an object with 15 variables in it and then I have my self object. I want to load those variables into self. Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to do it manually?

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own [copy] constructor which copies the members over, unless there's some sort of inheritance relationship between the classes.

Comment: `object1.__dict__.update(object2.__dict__)`?

Comment: Always worth asking, why do you want to do this?

Comment: The self variable with many important control states from another script is passed to me in this one. So I've got my current scripts self object and then another object that I'd like to add to the current self so I only need to pass a single variable across functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `__dict__` property: `self.__dict__.update(other.__dict__)`

There are corner cases where this won't work, notably for any variables defined in the class, rather than in a method (or in other "running code").

If you want to copy pretty much everything over:

```
for k in filter(lambda k: not k.startswith('_'), dir(other)): # avoid copying private items
    setattr(self, k, getattr(other, k))
```

Answer (score 2):

`vars(obj)` returns `obj.__dict__`

so

`vars(self).update(vars(obj))` works too

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object which works like a proxy - just call methods and variables of objects. In python you can use `__getattr__()` for that:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a1 = 1
        self.a2 = 2

    def a(self):
        return "a"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1 = 1
        self.b2 = 2

    def b(self):
        return "b"

class Combine:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.__objects = args

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for obj in self.__objects:
            try:
                return getattr(obj, name)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

        raise AttributeError

obj = Combine(A(), B())

print obj.a1, obj.a2, obj.a()
print obj.b1, obj.b2, obj.b()
```

Answer (score 0):

the quick-but-ugly (and unsafe) way of copying members from another object at once:

`self.__dict__.update(otherobj.__dict__)`

this will not copy methods and static (class) members however.

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in other.__dict__.items():
    # you might want to put other conditions here to check which attrs you want to copy and which you don't
    if k not in self.__dict__.keys():
        self.__dict__[k]=v
```